# PHP SQL functions don't return valid SQL datatype

Tags: php, mysql

So I am using the following functions to grab the datatype of certain fields in an SQL database.

```
$type  = mysql_field_type($result, $i);
$len   = mysql_field_len($result, $i);
```

I need to use these datatypes to ultimately structure another table. The problem is the returns I am getting from these functions are not valid SQL datatypes, I am getting returns like this: string (25), int (11), string (25)

Int is ok but string is not an SQL datatype, so do I need to figure out which returns need to be reformatted into correct datatypes and make functions to do that? Or am I missing another way to do it?

Comment: I would suggest the solution by Travesty3 - use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and/or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will see that the mysql_field_type() function will return the following data as per (http://it2.php.net/mysql_field_type):

```
CHAR, VARCHAR, TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT, ENUM, SET: string
TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, INTEGER, BIGINT: int
FLOAT, DOUBLE, DECIMAL, NUMERIC: real
TIMESTAMP: timestamp
YEAR: year
DATE: date
TIME: time
DATETIME: datetime
TINYBLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, LONGBLOB, BLOB: blob
```

Perhaps you can rather try something like:

```
$table = "my_table";
$result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE TABLE `{$tabler}`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $field = $row->Field;
    $type = $row->Type;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a query like this:

```
SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'databaseName' AND table_name = 'tableName' AND column_name = 'columnName';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `mysql_field_len` returns the schema length if it exists

> Will get the length of the id field as specified in the database
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-len.php

Also `string` is a valid return for `mysql_field_type`, not sure what the issue is.

**Example**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_username", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("mysql");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM func");
$fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);
$table  = mysql_field_table($result, 0);
echo "Your '" . $table . "' table has " . $fields . " fields and " . $rows . " record(s)\n";
echo "The table has the following fields:\n";
for ($i=0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $type  = mysql_field_type($result, $i);
    $name  = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    $len   = mysql_field_len($result, $i);
    $flags = mysql_field_flags($result, $i);
    echo $type . " " . $name . " " . $len . " " . $flags . "\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-type.php

Comment: Where in the description of `mysql_field_len` does it say that it returns the schema length? The description I see says "Returns the length of the specified field." And yes, `string` is a valid return for `mysql_field_type`, but is not a valid data type in MySQL, as the OP said in the post. He needs to use the existing column's data type to create another table, and `string` is not a valid MySQL data type when creating a table.